# results don't match using selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I want to fill data using selenium
but, results don't match

[image]
this is my code

```
    Dim Keys As Selenium.Keys
    Set Keys = New Selenium.Keys
    ch.SetClipBoard "Good Morning"
    ch.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='textbox']").Clear
    ch.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='textbox']").SendKeys Keys.Control + "V"
```

any idea ?

Comment: What is the problem here? Clear not working or the text pasted twice each time?

Comment: @Prophet  the text pasted twice each time?

target is to write Good Morning
not Good MorningGood Morning

Comment: I understand the target. So, you clearly see during the code run that the text area is cleared by `  ch.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='textbox']").Clear` command?

Comment: @Prophet yes sir

Comment: I want to write Good Morning

Comment: Well... I see nothing in the code here that could make the paste twice ...

Comment: yes
but the result is pasted twice 

Comment: @Prophet What version of Chrome are you using ?
I'm using version 105

Comment: 105 too. I'm guess it's not the issue with Chrome version. I really don't know what causes your issue

Comment: @Prophet 
Solved

I changed from
Keys.Control + "V"

Becomes
Keys.Control + "v"